# Where does the TCP/UDP connection happening from this given example?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have one open-source sample, which is working but i am not able to understand where is the TCP/UDP connection happening? `HHNET_LogonServer`

test.c:

```
#include "HHNet.h"
#include "HHDecoder.h"

#include "stdio.h"
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    HHERR_CODE      errCode;
    unsigned long   dwTmp;
    unsigned int    nPort;

    errCode     = HHERR_FAILURE;

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf("Usage:<./SDKDemo> <IP> <Username> <Password> <Data port>\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        dwTmp = strlen(*(argv + 1));
        if ( (dwTmp > 7) && (dwTmp < 15 )) {
            g_pIPString = (*(argv + 1));
        } else {
            printf("Invalid IP !\n");
        }
        g_pUseName  = argv[2];
        g_pPASSWD   = argv[3];

        if ((nPort = atoi(argv[4])) > 0) {
            g_lPort = nPort;
        }
    }

    errCode = HHNET_Startup(5000, LogonNotifyCallback, CheckUserPswCallback, UpdateFileCallback, ServerMsgCmdCallback, StreamWriteCheckCallback, (ChannelStreamCallback)PreviewStreamCallback);
    printf(">HHNET_Startup: %s\n", errCode?"Failed!":"Successful!");

    HANDLE m_hLogonServer;  
    errCode = HHNET_LogonServer(g_pIPString, g_lPort, "admin", g_pUseName, g_pPASSWD, 0, &m_hLogonServer);
    printf(">HHNET_LogonServer: %s\n",errCode?"Failed!":"Successful!");

    errCode = HHNET_LogoffServer(m_hLogonServer);

    if (errCode) {
        printf("Error code:%d\n", errCode);
        printf(">HHNET_LogoffServer: Failed!\n");
    } else  {
        printf(">HHNET_LogoffServer: Successful!\n");
    }
     HHNET_Cleanup();
     return 0;
}
```

HHNet.h: ( https://gist.github.com/3067481 )

```
HHERR_CODE      HHNET_LogonServer(IN  CHAR *pServerIP,IN  UINT nServerPort,IN  CHAR *pDeviceName,IN  CHAR *pUserName,IN  CHAR *pUserPassword,IN UINT dwClientID,OUT  HANDLE *hLogonServer);
```

HHDecoder.h: ( https://gist.github.com/3067481 )

Output:

```
$ ./test 192.168.0.199 admin admin 5000
sh: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time: Permission denied
sh: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl: Permission denied
sh: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes: Permission denied
>HHNET_Startup: Successful!
--->|   HHNET_LogonServer :192.168.0.199
>HHNET_LogonServer: Successful!
>HHNET_LogoffServer: Successful!
```

But i can not figure out where is this trigger happening `--->| HHNET_LogonServer :192.168.0.199`

Comment: My guess is that it's happening inside `HNET_LogonServer()`. Start by checking the source of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it in your question

```
HHNET_LogonServer(IN  CHAR *pServerIP,IN  UINT nServerPort,IN  CHAR *pDeviceName,IN  CHAR *pUserName,IN  CHAR *pUserPassword,IN UINT dwClientID,OUT  HANDLE *hLogonServer);
```

Inside this function, a socket is created and connected to the remote.

Comment: YES - my mistake because its a library closed source, i was expecting the functions also open which was not. e.g: `gcc -o ./test -Wall -g -L../lib/ -I../include/ test.o   -lHHNet -lm -lpthread`